# "%s" random concatenation in R

Tags: r, random, append

I am looking for a way to concatenate a string or a number (3 digits at least) into a save file.
For instance, in python I can use `'%s' % [format(str), format(number)])` and add it to csv file with a random generator.

How do I generate a random number into a format in R?
That is my save file and I want to add a random string or a number in the end of the file name:

```
file = paste(path, 'group1N[ADD FORMAT HERE].csv',sep = '')

file = paste(path, 'group1N.csv',sep = '') to become -- >

file = paste(path, 'group1N212.csv',sep = '') or file = paste(path, 'group1Nkut.csv',sep = '')
```

after using a random generator of strings or numbers and appending it to the save .csv file, each time it is saved, as a random generated end of file

Comment: can you show some example to test.  It is not clear what format you need

Comment: Do you want it to be random? Or do you want it be unique?  Are you looking for just adding a counter to the end or do you want true random with the possibility of overwriting a different file?

Comment: I want it to be random. I want to have the possibility to write a different file each time I run the code.

Comment: @theundecided - which is why I asked. Truly random wouldn't guarantee a different file each time. If you want that guarantee then a sequential generator works probably be better. Or at least check to make sure it's not a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the built-in `tempfile()` function:

```r
 tempfile(pattern="group1N", tmpdir=".", fileext=".csv")
[1] "./group1N189d494eaaf2ea.csv"
```

(if you don't specify `tmpdir` the results go to a session-specific temporary directory).

This won't write over existing files; given that there are 14 hex digits in the random component, I think the "very likely to be unique" in the description is an understatement ... (i.e. at a rough guess the probability of collision might be something like 16^(-14) ...)

> The names are very likely to be unique among calls to ‘tempfile’
> in an R session and across simultaneous R sessions (unless
> ‘tmpdir’ is specified).  The filenames are guaranteed not to be
> currently in use.